# Автоматическое нажатие на кнопку

Tags: javascript

Какой js код позволяет при перезагрузке странице или вообще при ее первом посещение - автоматически выбрать какой-нибудь элемент(по нажатию на который выполняется некий load код). **Тобишь зашел - и сразу погрузило, на кнопку нажимать не надо.**

Comment: class active не то

Comment: напишите функцию на js, и вызывайте при  загрузке страницы.

Answer (score 1):

Процесс загрузки HTML-документа:
DOMContentLoaded – браузер полностью загрузил HTML, и построил DOM-дерево.
load – браузер загрузил все ресурсы.
beforeunload/unload – уход со страницы.

```js
//Событие onload на window срабатывает, когда загружается вся страница.
 window.onload = function() {
    console.log("Все загрузилось");
  };
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
 <meta charset="UTF-8">
 </head>
<body>
<script>
  //DOMContentLoaded – браузер полностью загрузил HTML, и построил DOM-дерево.
  function ready() {
    console.log('DOM готов');
    console.log("Тут можно выполнять необходимые действия");
  }

  document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", ready);
</script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score -1):

location.href="download.php" или лучше на php header

Answer (score -3):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <button type="button" id="ya">Нажать</button>

    <script>
function raz() {
  alert("Здравствуйте");
}
raz(); // функция запускается без события
document.getElementById("ya").addEventListener("click", raz);
</script>
</body>
</html>
```